# How to keep Navigation Bar elements from overlapping when resizing window?

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML. It looks correct in full screen. When resizing the browser, specifically making it smaller, the nav bar elements overlap each other. I can't figure out how to fix it. I've also included the CSS. I'm guessing it has to do with the positioning? I tried adding relative position to the nav element, but it didn't fix the problem. Any input is appreciated. Thank you.

```css
#mainNav {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.dropButton {
  background-color: #F4D35E;
  color: #083D77;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 28px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropButton a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropDown a:hover {
  color: #ED2E07;
}

.dropDown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F4D35E;
  color: #083D77;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #083D77;
}

.featRecipe {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-left: 75px;
}

.drink1,
.drink2 {
  margin-right: 110px;
}

.featRecipe li {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.drinkOfTheDay {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-left: 75px;
}

.imgOTD,
.image,
.ingr {
  margin-right: 75px;
}

#libNav li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.library {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.drink {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.top {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
html {
    background: #EBEBD3;
}
#siteTitle {
    font-family: "Brush Script MT", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #ED2E07;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#pageTitle {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
    color: #ED2E07;
}
.body {
    color: #083D77;
    text-align: center;
}
main {
    color: #083D77;
    font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}
main h2,h3,h4 {
    color: #F95738;
}

.featRecipe h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #083D77;
    font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}
.dir li {
    max-width: 500px;
}
#libNav a {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #083D77;
}
.library h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #EBEBD3;
}

.dropDown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropDown:hover .dropButton {
  background-color: #EE964B;
}

img {
    border: solid 5px #F95738;
}
#libNav a:visited {
    color: #083D77;  
}
.top a, a:visited {
    color: #083D77;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.dropButton a:visited {
    color: #083D77;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
      color: #ED2E07;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name="author" content="Roman Kudryashov" />
  <meta name="description" content="Drinkmastery.com provides a library of cocktails for drink enthusiasts, connoisseurs, and restaurant professionals." />
  <meta name="keywords" content="coktails, drinks, bar, bartending, mixology, vodka, rum, gin, tequila, whiskey, mixed drinks, recipes, liquor, liquer" />
  <title>Drink Mastery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/layout.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/format.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/effects.css">
  <script>
    function con() {
      var ans = window.confirm("Are you 21+ years old?\n\nPress \"OK\" if Yes, \"Cancel\" if NO");

      if (ans == false) {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
      }
    }
    window.setTimeout("con()", 2000);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="siteTitle">Drink Mastery</h1>

  <nav id="mainNav">
    <div class="dropDown">
      <a href="home.html" class="dropButton">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropDown">
      <a href="featuredCocktails.html" class="dropButton">Featured Cocktails</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropDown">
      <a href="seasonalCocktails.html" class="dropButton">Seasonal Cocktails</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="xmasDrinks.html">Christmas Drinks</a>
        <a href="springFavorites.html">Spring Favorites</a>
        <a href="summerDrinks.html">Summer Drinks</a>
        <a href="fallSpecials.html">Fall Specials</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropDown">
      <a href="drinkLibrary.html" class="dropButton">Drink Library</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="vodka.html">Vodka</a>
        <a href="rum.html">Rum</a>
        <a href="gin.html">Gin</a>
        <a href="tequila.html">Tequila</a>
        <a href="whiskey.html">Whiskey</a>
        <a href="misc.html">Miscellaneous</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropDown">
      <a href="resources.html" class="dropButton">Resources</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="bartendingTips.html">Bartending Tips &amp; Tricks</a>
        <a href="education.html">Educational Articles</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropDown">
      <a href="aboutUs.html" class="dropButton">About Us</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <h2 id="pageTitle">Welcome to Drink Mastery!</h2>
  <p class="body">We strive to provide you with a complete library of various cocktail recipes! Happy mixing!</p>
  <main>
    <h3 id="dotd" style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; color: #EE964B">Drink of the Day</h3>
    <div class="drinkOfTheDay">
      <img src="../images/mojito.jpg" alt="Mojito" height="300" class="imgOTD">
      <div class="ingr">
        <h4>Ingredients</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>10 fresh mint leaves</li>
          <li>1/2 lime, cut into 4 wedges</li>
          <li>2 ablespoons of white sugar</li>
          <li>1.5 oz white rum</li>
          <li>1/2 cup club soda</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Directions</h4>
        <ol class="dir">
          <li>Place mint leaves and 1 lime wedge into a sturdy glass. Use a muddler to crush the mint and lime to release the mint oils and lime juice.</li>
          <li>Add 2 more lime wedges and the sugar, and muddle again to release the lime juice.</li>
          <li>Fill the glass almost to the top with ice.</li>
          <li>Pour the rum over the ice, and fill the glass with carbonated water.</li>
          <li>Stir, taste, and add more sugar if desired. Garnish with the remaining lime wedge.</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Created by Roman Kudryashov</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CSS for `dropDown` to

```
.dropDown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Then add some padding or margin to that so they're not touching.

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference between inline-block and inline-flex?

Comment: I'd recommend adding `text-align: center;` to `#mainNav` also. Flex allows the items not to touch each other when you've positioned them differently within your CSS, this seemed the easiest fix. I'd also add `margin-top: 10px;` to `dropDown` so that they don't touch completely.

Comment: Thank you. It looks much better with the fixes!